# Can't start the container of a nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker

Yes, I've already searched, I wouldn't ask if I hadn't already done so :/

The following **nginx-proxy.conf** is installed in one of my servers. It adds SSL to webapp1 which runs as a container on the same host on port 8080:

```
server
{
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 server_name webapp1.home.local;

location /
 {
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_pass http://192.168.1.100:8080/;
 }

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name webapp1.home.local;
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
   rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

**I would like to move nginx into a container.**
I need a Dockerfile and I do not want to use docker-compose. It is not compatible with Podman for several reasons.

My **Dockerfile** is:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx-proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-proxy.conf
COPY cert.pem /etc/ssl/cert.pem
COPY key.pem /etc/ssl/private/key.pem
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx"]
```

And this is how I build/run it:

```
docker build -t reverse-proxy:0.1 .
docker run -d --name=nginx-rev-proxy -p 80:80 -p 443:443 reverse-proxy:0.1
```

When I run `docker ps -a` it outputs "`Exited(0)`" and on the Port column there's nothing. Literally empty.
`docker logs <container-id>` is empty too.

I'm working on it the whole day :/ If somebody could tell me what's wrong that would be awesome :)

Thank you

Comment: Does deleting the `CMD` line help?  (Also consider whether you actually want to copy your private key into an image: anyone who gets a copy of the image can trivially extract it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nginx` Docker Hub image already includes a `CMD` that launches Nginx as a foreground process, so just deleting the `CMD` from your derived Dockerfile will make this start up.

In general, when you start a Docker container, its default command must run as a foreground process.  If the command ever exits (including to launch itself in a background or daemonized mode) then the container will exit as well.  Nginx's default is to launch itself as a daemon process, which is why it's exiting (successfully) in your example.  The [Docker Hub `nginx` Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/5c15613519a26c6adc244c24f814a95c786cfbc3/mainline/buster/Dockerfile#L103) sets a command-line option to disable this behavior

```sh
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: From my side I can say that I also tried the full `CMD` command as your example (and docker hub) suggest, but it was probably during a proxy.conf "fine-tuning" and when it wasn't starting I was blaming the full-CMD, which later became (and remained) just `CMD ["nginx"]`. So many and many thanks for explaining that! (: